# Cannot drill far enough to mount curtain pole

Tags: drill

Trying to mount a curtain pole above my window, and I cannot drill far enough in to get a rawlplug plus screw into the wall.  I can drill ~0.75in deep but no further.

I have considered getting a heavier duty drill to do the job, but I am worried that it may be something I shouldn't be drilling in to such as a lintel.

What's the solution for mounting a curtain pole in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing here, but it sounds like you're trying to drill into stone/cement/concrete. If so, you need a drill bit meant for rock and a percussion/ hammer drill. You can buy cheapy hammer drills that won't last very long (harbor freight comes to mind if you're in the US), or rent them.

Oh, and the only thing you *don't* want to drill into is electrical/plumbing/gas. Everything else is fair game. (Though, now that I think of it, if you're unlucky enough to have a steel beam across your window, you'll have to revisit your strategy.)